# change color of text in paragraph without making it wrap(described every thing below) Bootstrap/css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, deployment, responsive-design, responsiveness

I want to change the color of specific letters in a paragraph in HTML, but when I use
**span**  **strong** it makes my the specific letter wrap to next line in smaller widths and text becomes too difficult to read I want it not to wrap but change size vw is not working tho. That is the problem shown in image it becomes like this.

[image]

## It stays same no matter how width changes or last text  move to next line****

My code

```
          <li className="   border  rounded mt-3 text-white ">
            <div className="display  text-decoration-none w-100 h-100  "><p className="d-flex text-center"> 
              <div className="text-info text-center ">User123 </div>
               <p className="">Lorem ipsum. </p><p className="text-info ">3lorem1</p>  <p className="text-info ">User123 </p>on 
              <p> 12-12-2023</p>
              </p> </div>
          </li>
```

I have tried vw but it does not work too cuz text still wraps cant add 100 breakpoints. I want it to stay like this while no matter how width changes or last text to next line.

[image]

Comment: Difficult to know without the CSS.

Comment: i am using bootstrap only no css